# How to build using MSBuild and wait until it is finished?

Tags: python, visual-studio, cmd, msbuild, wait

I am running

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /build Release Kodex.All.sln
```

from windows cmd.

This works fine, but returns immediately. The binaries are still being created several minutes after the command has returned, and the console is silent.

I need this as part of a build pipeline, which needs to copy and package the resulting compiled binaries.

Running this command returns immediately, but I need to be sure that it has finished or to wait for errors before moving on.

How do I do that?

Bonus: How do I do that with python?

Comment: Does it change when you write `start "" /WAIT "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\…\devenv.exe" …`?

Comment: @aschipfl This also returns immediately